# EF7 migration in Pluralsight course

Tags: migration, entity-framework-core

Is anyone else having problems with the second migration in Shawn Wildermuth's Pluralsight course "Building a Web App with ASP.NET Core RC1, MVC 6, EF7 & AngularJS"?

Specifically, the command

```
dnx ef migrations add IdentityEntities
```

causes this exception:

```
GenericArguments[0], 'TheWorld.Models.IWorldRepository', on 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbContextFactory`1[TContext]' violates the constraint of type 'TContext'.
```

The first migration and database creation seemed to go fine, so I'm not sure what's causing this.

Answer (score 6):

I just fixed this by deleting the entire Migrations folder from Solution Explorer. I am not sure exactly what causes this error, but I think if you name your migrations the same thing (IdentityEntities in your case) the problem is likely to occur.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you should specify a migration name and the context explicitly as parameters. I am not sure what is it meant to look like when using `dnx`, but when using the Package Manager Console inside Visual Studio the correct command is

```
Add-Migration -Name "MyProjectMigration" -Context "MyProjectContext"
```

I have first tried simple

```
Add-Migration MyProjectContext
```

which has generated 2 files, and after that

```
Database-Update
```

and the result was the `System.ArgumentException: GenericArguments[0], 'SqliteEfcExample.Migrations.MyProjectContext', on 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IDbContextFactory 1[TContext]' violates the constraint of type 'TContext'.`

I have then deleted the 2 files generated by `Add-Migration MyProjectContext` (thanks to @brendan-l for the hint) and re-created them with `Add-Migration -Name "MyProjectMigration" -Context "MyProjectContext"` and after that

```
Update-Database -Context "MyProjectContext"
```

worked just fine.