# Missing dotnet.exe

Tags: .net, testing, .net-core

I'm a bit stuck.
I have a Windows Server 2019 standard
According to the registry I have dotNet 4.8 installed
But I have no dotnet.exe anywhere. This usually lives in C:\Program Files\dotnet
I need the dotnet CLI so I can run tests, e.g. `dotnet test [<PROJECT> | <SOLUTION> | <DIRECTORY> | <DLL>]`
What do I need to install to get the CLI in order to run the tests using dotnet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the dotnet command executable located on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588392/where-is-the-dotnet-command-executable-located-on-windows)

Comment: The `dotnet` executable is for the "new" .NET (version 5 and up), the registry is saying you have the "old" .NET Framework version 4.

Comment: @JoeSewell And .NET Core...

Comment: @JoeSewell `dotnet` is a part of .NET Core at least from version 2.0+, so it covers not only .NET 5+.

Comment: Yes, thank you both for clarifying. The "new" .NET was known as .NET Core in versions 1.x, 2.x, and 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

`dotnet` tool is a part of .NET Core, so you have to install .NET 5 for example. You can check what [version of .NET Core has been released on this page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core).

Tool is a [part of SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/).

.NET Framework 4.8 is not a part of the .NET Core.

Comment: So I need .net Core, is that the runtime or the SDK? If Runtime, is it the one for running console, desktop or server apps? I want to run unit/specflow tests