# How do I generate EF Core migrations in a Visual Studio 2015 WinForms project?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-core

I am exploring the new Entity Framework Core (NOT in conjunction with ASP.Net, nor under Linux, what I am coding is just a classic WinForms app built with Visual Studio under Windows 7 64-bit using SQLite as the database engine).

1. Trying to reproduce [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/netcore/new-db-sqlite) I have found out that I need the `dotnet.exe` tool that is not a part of Visual Studio 2015 and to be installed with [.NET Core tools preview for Visual Studio](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2015).
2. After having installed it I have faced another error: while trying to execute `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -c SqliteEfcExampleContext`: `No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"`.
3. I have then Googled upon a hint saying I need to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` with NuGet.
4. It refused to install saying I need a more recent version of NuGet itself. So I have updated NuGet from `https://dotnet.myget.org/F/nuget-beta/vsix/`.

But I still can't install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` - it says `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 1.1.0-preview4-final' has a package type 'DotnetCliTool' that is not supported by project 'SqliteEfcExample'.

How do I create the migrations anyway?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer myself, let me share it again...

After executing the steps described in the question I have

1. Installed [Windows Management Framework 5.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395) to get PowerShell updated.
2. Went to `Tools - NuGet Package Manager - Package Manager Console` to execute the following command manually: `PM> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Pre`.
3. Then I have found relevant Package Manager Console commands (Add-Migration, Update-Database, Scaffold-DbContext, etc.) working and used `Add-Migration SqliteEfcExampleContext` to generate the migration code for the model code I've already written.

**UPDATE:**

The quest has continued and I have faced another problem - the `... violates the constraint of type 'TContext'` error trying to use the above mentioned commands then. I have described it together with the solution in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42591219/274627) to a question about the same error found in slightly different context.

Comment: It would be really great if you could elaborate on #3. Perhaps a step by step example?